# How to generate Authorization code in Jmeter with Oauth PKCE flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter, pkce

I'm trying to generate Authorization code in Jmeter with Oauth PKCE flow could'nt extract code any thoughts here would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer your application documentation as the implementations might be different.

Some parameters cannot be "extracted", i.e. you need to know your `client_id` beforehand.

Some parameters needs to be generated, if no documentation is available you can use i.e. [Call Your API Using the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce) which contains comprehensive explanation and example code snippets for creating `code_verifier` and `code_challenge`

Example code for `code_verifier` generation:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
byte[] code = new byte[32];
sr.nextBytes(code);
String verifier = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(code);

log.info('code_verifier: ' + verifier)

vars.put('verifier', verifier)
```

[image]

Example code for `code_challenge`

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

byte[] bytes = vars.get('verifier').getBytes("US-ASCII");
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
md.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
byte[] digest = md.digest();
String challenge = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(digest);

log.info('code_challenge: ' + challenge)
```

[image]

The code can be invoked from the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) using [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) as the language