# For OAuth PKCE flow in JMeter unable to extract Code values

Tags: groovy, oauth-2.0, jmeter, pkce

In JMeter unable to extract the code_verifier and code_challenge values.

Referred this post, [How to generate Authorization code in Jmeter with Oauth PKCE flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73294288/how-to-generate-authorization-code-in-jmeter-with-oauth-pkce-flow)

but while executing the code getting error as, "ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor - code_challenge javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getBytes() on null object"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're blindly copying and pasting the code from the referred answer - make sure to copy and paste the `code_verifier` piece as well because the error you're getting most probably means that `verifier` variable is [null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java) (doesn't have respective value)

Make sure to properly generate the `verifier` variable and ensure that it's there by checking [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) (look for `code_verifier` line) and/or by adding a [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) which allows inspecting which [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are defined and see their values